# bat file read in file

Tags: date, batch-file

i have a text file datefile.txt that contains

10-06-2013

and I tried to read it using the following bat file:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ datefile.txt"`) do (
    set "var=%%a"
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "var=!var:*:=!"
    echo(!var!
    ENDLOCAL
)
echo %var%
```

the output I got are these:

```
10/06/2013
1:10/06/2013
```

how come my %var% is different from above one.
Or how could I remove "1:" in the %var%?

thanks.

Comment: I would really recommend you PowerShell if you have access to it. It makes life so easier.

Comment: i'm almost there...just need to remove that "1:" ....please help if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got this type of output, as the first line is written by `echo(!var!`.
The second line by `echo %var%`, but in the second case the variable doesn't contain the same.

This is because the Setlocal/endlocal block inside the for loop.

In your case you can simply remove the block, as your date doesn't contains any exclamation marks nor carets.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ datefile.txt"`) do (
    set "var=%%a"
    set "var=!var:*:=!"
    echo(!var!
)
echo %var%
```

And if your file contains only one line, the solution could be simplified by

```
<datefile.tx set /p var=
echo %var%
```

Comment: Very educational! Explains very well. Thank you!  - my way of doing it is just a dirty trick without understanding the real logic of dos commands....

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to remove the "1:" using dos substr replacement:

http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringOperations.php#Snippets.Remove